# Javascript get object property and sub-property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access an object property like this:

```
var scope1 = {a: {value: 25}};
var scope2 = undefined;

var v1 = scope1.b.value || 0;  // TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
var v2 = scope2.b.value || 0;  // TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

apparentl the || operator doesn't give me what I want.  I know I can do the following instead

```
var vv2 = (scope1 && scope1.b ? scope1.b.value : 0);
```

But this makes the code really lengthy...  So anyone know if there's easier ways to do what I want to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual answer is the `&&` operator:

```
var v1 = scope1.b && scope1.b.value || 0;
```

...because like `||`, `&&` is [curiously powerful](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html): `&&` evaluates the left-hand operand and, if it's falsey, takes that falsey value as its result; if the left-hand operand value is truthy, `&&` evaluates the right-hand operand and takes that value as its result.

So if `scope1.b` is `undefined`:

```
// We start with
scope1.b && scope1.b.value || 0
// which is
undefined && scope1.b.value || 0
// which is
undefined || 0
// which is
0
```

...but if `scope.b` is a truthy value like an object reference:

```
// We start with
scope1.b && scope1.b.value || 0
// which is
scope1.b.value || 0
// which is
scope1.b.value // *IF* scope1.b.value is truthy, or
0              // If it isn't
```

*(Recall that the "falsey" values are `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`; and "truthy" values are all others.)*

Example:

```js
var scope1;

scope1 = {a: "foo"};
snippet.log(scope1.b && scope1.b.value || 0); // 0

scope1 = {a: "foo", b: {}};
snippet.log(scope1.b && scope1.b.value || 0); // 0

scope1 = {a: "foo", b: {value: 42}};
snippet.log(scope1.b && scope1.b.value || 0); // 42
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

I'm not recommending it, but you *could* write a function for this that handles arbitrary depths:

```js
function resolve(obj, path, defValue) {
  var rv = path.split(".").reduce(function(o, p) {
    return o && o[p];
  }, obj);
  return rv || defValue;
}

var scope1;

scope1 = {a: "foo"};
snippet.log(resolve(scope1, "b.value", 0)); // 0

scope1 = {a: "foo", b: {}};
snippet.log(resolve(scope1, "b.value", 0)); // 0

scope1 = {a: "foo", b: {value: 42}};
snippet.log(resolve(scope1, "b.value", 0)); // 42

scope1 = {a: "foo", b: {}};
snippet.log(resolve(scope1, "b.baz.boz.value", 0)); // 0

scope1 = {a: "foo", b: {baz: {boz: {value: 67}}}};
snippet.log(resolve(scope1, "b.baz.boz.value", 0)); // 67
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

That implementation doesn't support brackets notation, just dot notation, but you can freely write `resolve(obj, "foo.0.bar.42", 0)` if you had numeric indexes you needed, since it's not subject to the standard JavaScript parsing rules. (Or extending it to support `[]` wouldn't be that hard.)

Comment: got it! this is absolutely helpful!!  so && is the best (or the shortest code) we can do with javascript right?

Comment: @ChandlerLee: Unless you want to write a function for it and do `var v1 = foo(scope1, "b.value", 0);`, which is probably overkill. :-) I added an example of doing that. The last couple of examples *are* shorter than `var v1 = scope1.b && scope1.b.baz && scope1.b.baz.boz && scope1.b.baz.boz.value || 0;` would be...